# Find a resolvent of operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I need to find a resolvent for the next operator
\begin{equation}
Ax(t)=\int _{0}^{1} t* \sin(s)x(s)ds
\end{equation}
I know that I should use that $Ax(t)-\lambda Ax(t)=Ay(t)$. I got that
\begin{equation}
\int _{0}^{1}\sin(s)x(s)ds=\frac{y(t)}{(1-\lambda)t}
\end{equation}
I have no idea how to get $x(t)$ from the equation, so I hope for your help.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the definition of $Ax$. What is $*$ inside the integral?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $z(s)=\sin s$ and $t(s)=s$, the operator $A$ can be written as
$$
Ax=\langle x,z\rangle\,t. 
$$
This in particular shows that $A$ is a rank-one operator. As such, it can only have one non-zero eigenvalue, which from the equality $At=\langle x,z\rangle\,t$ we see that it is $\langle t,z\rangle$. So the spectrum of $A$ is $\{0,\langle t,z\rangle\}$. The actual value of $\langle t,z\rangle$ is $\sin1-\cos1$, but we gain little from expressing it explicitly.

Because $x$ appears inside an inner product, you cannot expect to solve directly for it. But what one can gather from the fact that $A^2$ is a multiple of $A$, is that for $\lambda\not\in\sigma(A)$ it is a good guess to assume that $(A-\lambda I)^{-1}=\alpha A+\beta I$. If this were the case, we would have
\begin{align}
I&=(\alpha A+\beta I)(A-\lambda I)
=\alpha A^2+(\beta-\alpha\lambda)A-\beta\lambda\,I\\[0.3cm]
&=(\alpha\langle t,z\rangle+\beta-\alpha\lambda)A-\beta\lambda I. 
\end{align}
This forces
$$
-\beta\lambda=1,\qquad\qquad \alpha\langle t,z\rangle+\beta-\alpha\lambda=0.
$$
We get
$$
\beta=-\frac1\lambda,\qquad\qquad \alpha=\frac1{\lambda(\langle t,z\rangle-\lambda)}.
$$
In other words, for $\lambda\ne0$, $\lambda\ne\langle t,z\rangle$,
$$
(A-\lambda I)^{-1}=\frac1{\lambda(\langle t,z\rangle-\lambda)}\,A-\frac1\lambda\,I.
$$
If you wanted to write this in the original notation,  you would have
$$
(A-\lambda )^{-1}x(t)=-\frac1\lambda\,x(t)+\frac t{\lambda(\sin1-\cos1-\lambda)}\,\int_0^1 x(s)\,\sin s\,ds
$$
for $\lambda\ne0$, $\lambda\ne\sin1-\cos1$.